# Why is x=0 equivalent to x=''

Tags: javascript

I am stumped as to why the below console.log is not called based on the code below.  x certainly does not equal '' since it is set to 0

```js
var x=0;

if (x!=''){
  console.log('here', x);
}
```

Comment: Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: JavaScript runs on `falsy/truthy` comparisons only. You need to use `!==` or `===` to compare types as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using [Loose Equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using)

> Loose equality compares two values for equality, after converting both values to a common type. After conversions (one or both sides may undergo conversions), the final equality comparison is performed exactly as `===` performs it.

The `==` converts both the operands to common type. Here `0` is `Number` so it will convert `''` to `Number` using `Number('')` And `Number('')` returns `0` so thats why `0 == ''`.
If you want to avoid this you may use `===` and `!==`

```js
console.log(Number(''))//0

var x = 0;
if (x !== ''){
  console.log('here', x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `!==` instead of `!=`

```js
var x = 0;

if (x !== ''){
  console.log('here', x);
}
```

Same goes for `===` instead of `==`

This is because the triple equals checks the type as well, otherwise the values get coerced into being "truthy" or "falsey" values.

```js
console.log(0 == '');   //>true
console.log(0 === '');  //>false
console.log(3 == '3');  //>true
console.log(3 === '3'); //>false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good article explaining "truthiness" and "falsiness" in JavaScript:

https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/

To get around it, use strict comparisons, !== and ===.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 0 is a falsy value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

```
if (0) console.log("hi, I'm a falsy value)
```

if you want to check the exact type and value try === operator

```
if (x === 0) console.log("zero here)
```